# LoadLibrary with Absolute Path returns Incorrect HMODULE with No Error

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, absolute-path, loadlibrary

I have some code which is trying to load a Dll.

I have encountered an odd 'error' with this. When trying to load the dll from an absolute path, I get a Non-Null HMODULE that gives no windows error codes on a GetLastError call (i.e. GetLastError returns '0' or success according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). When calling into a function in this dll, I get incorrect values.

This behavior is peculiar, because if, instead, I switch the current directory to be that of my current dll using SetCurrentDirectory and use a relative path call to LoadLibrary, I get correct values.

Here is a snippet describing the situation:

Using absolute path:

```
std::string libLoc = get_dll_location(); // Get the directory of this dll
HMODULE myDLL = LoadLibraryA(libLoc.c_str()); // Non-null value
DWORD lastError = GetLastError(); // returns 0

MyObj * value = UseDLL(myDLL); // bad value
```

Using relative path:

```
SetCurrentDirectory("c:\\path\\containing\\dll\\"); // hard coded path to dll's folder
HMODULE myDLL = LoadLibrary("myDll.dll");  // Non-null value
MyObj * value = UseDLL(myDLL);  // Good value
```

I'd really like to avoid having to use SetCurrentDirectory, because the application using this Dll may be multi-threaded and require that the directory stays the same.

Any insight on this issue would be much appreciated. Hopefully, this is just a minor bug on my part.

**Update**: Using [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to be out of the question, as the LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_* flags don't appear to be available to me (I've already tried installing the [KB2533623 update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533623)).

Comment: [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) with alternate search path is likely your best bet.

Comment: More likely something else going on that's not obvious.  Is the 'UseDLL' impacted by the directory change?   What happens if you use a 'LoadLibrary' with a hard-coded relative path (but not changing current directory)?

Comment: Only slightly related, but did you intend to include the DLL name in your SetCurrentDirectory() path call ?

Comment: @WhozCraig This looks to be a solid function and I'll see if it works, but the LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR flag is only available for windows 7 and above - this may introduce backwards compatability issues.

Comment: If that is the case, relying on the search path via LoadLibrary is going to be your only bet, and I would suggest you read David's answer several times over below. I *hate* relying on the system search path for anything besides OS libs only because it can be such a security hole if properly exploited. It sounds like you have a better idea of whats going on though, which is good.

Comment: @WhozCraig Do you know what dependencies are required for LoadLibraryEx's flags? The msdn you linked to says an update is required, but it seems that I already have it.

Comment: Provided you have the proper KB-update installed (via Windows Update, an inclusive service pack, or stand-alone installer like those listed in the article) the functionality you desire should be available. I'm afraid I'm only privy to the same info you are beyond that.

Comment: Hi funseiki, there's no reason that you should not be able to use LoadLibraryEx (at least on Windows 7 with http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533623 installed. See my updated answer for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that `MyDll.dll` has dependencies on other DLLs that reside in the same folder as `MyDll.dll`. When your application lives in a different folder from `MyDll.dll`, those dependencies will not be resolved from the folder that contains `MyDll.dll`. Instead they are resolved by the system [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx).

Your use `SetCurrentDirectory` influences the system DLL search order. And it means that the dependencies of `MyDll.dll` are resolved from the directory that contains `MyDll.dll`.

You can test this hypothesis by using, for example, Dependency Walker in profile mode. That will tell you how the dependencies of `MyDll.dll` are resolved at runtime.

You are right to dislike the use of `SetCurrentDirectory`. The best solution would be to put all the DLLs in the same directory as the application.

Of course, the other possibility is that the call to `UseDLL` has a dependency on the working directory. You can rule that out by changing the working directory back to its original value after the call to `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: I think you're right, should have realized that. Now I need to figure out how to get myDll.dll's dependencies to load from the new directory - LoadLibraryEx looks promising.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting SetDllDirectory or AddDllDirectory instead of SetCurrentDirectory, and use LoadLibraryEx with flag LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS instead of LoadLibrary. Useful information can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Update: Example of AddDllDirectory and associated calls on Windows 7 (requires KB2533623)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE (WINAPI *ADD_DLL_PROC)(PCWSTR);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *REMOVE_DLL_PROC)(DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE);

#ifndef LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS
#define LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS       0x00000400
#endif

int main()
{

    ADD_DLL_PROC lpfnAdllDllDirectory = (ADD_DLL_PROC)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "AddDllDirectory");
    REMOVE_DLL_PROC lpfnRemoveDllDirectory = (REMOVE_DLL_PROC)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "RemoveDllDirectory");
    if(lpfnAdllDllDirectory && lpfnRemoveDllDirectory)
    {

        DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE cookie = ((ADD_DLL_PROC)lpfnAdllDllDirectory)(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\");
        std::cout << cookie << std::endl;
        HMODULE module = LoadLibraryEx(L"cabview.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
        if(module)
        {
            std::cout << "Locked and loaded" << std::endl;
            FreeLibrary(module);
        }
        if(cookie && ((REMOVE_DLL_PROC)(cookie)))
        {
            std::cout << "Added and removed cookie" << std::endl;
        }


    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I have kernel32.lib referenced, but AddDllDirectory and many of the flags for LoadLibraryEx are missing. Are there other dependencies required to use these?

Comment: What's your development environment (for instance Visual Studio) and version?

Comment: Try adding #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502     
#endif to your stdafx.h file. I take it you have included Windows.h?

Comment: Hmm it's the Windows version. Use GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "AddlDllDirectory"); The function looks like DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE  WINAPI AddDllDirectory(
  _In_  PCWSTR NewDirectory
);
Alternatively, SetDllDirectory should do without the hoops (AddDllDirectory is useful when you have several search paths to add). Does that work?

Comment: I believe AddDllDirectory is only available on Windows 8 according to the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19173/discussion-between-anthill-and-funseiki)

Comment: Is SetDllDirectory process wide, or per thread? If the former then its use could lead to problems.

Comment: SetDllDirectory and AddDllDirectory are process-wide as far as I am aware, so yes, it is associated with quite a few potential pitfalls.

Comment: @Anthill I was able to get it to work - a non-dll file was being loaded from a local directory, so I needed to change that. As far as using AddDllDirectory, GetProcAddress was returning a NULL handle. I believe the error I received was 127 - procedure not found :/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it has been very useful. For those interested, DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE is a typedef of HANDLE.